# qsort const pointer problems

Tags: c, pointers, casting, constants

```
char  **av;
SIZE_T  ac;

char WordCopy[256] = {0};
av[ac] = strdup(p);

qsort(av, ac, sizeof (char *), compare);

STATIC int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const char *pp1 = *(const char **)p1;
    const char *pp2 = *(const char **)p2;
    return strcmp(pp1, pp2);
}
```

But, it gives me the following error:

```
complete.c: In function ‘compare’:
complete.c:26:24: error: cast discards ‘__attribute__((const))’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=cast-qual]
     const char *pp1 = *(const char **)p1;
                        ^
complete.c:27:24: error: cast discards ‘__attribute__((const))’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=cast-qual]
     const char *pp2 = *(const char **)p2;
                        ^
```

The old way it was written, works:

```
STATIC int
compare(p1, p2)
    CONST char  **p1;
    CONST char  **p2;
{
    return strcmp(*p1, *p2);
}
```

I don't understand what the difference is... why am I getting the casting error?  I found a few other similar-lokking issues here, which seemed to suggest that the syntax I am using *should* work... but it clearly does not.

I'd rather do it "properly" and not just disable the warning (disabling warnings will not pass code review).

**EDIT**: User chux asked what happened if I set a new var.. here is the result:

```
const char **s1 = (const char **)p1;
```

Produces:

```
complete.c: In function ‘compare’:
complete.c:26:23: error: cast discards ‘__attribute__((const))’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=cast-qual]
     const char **s1 = (const char **)p1;
                       ^
```

Comment: What warning occurs with `const char **s1 = (const char **)p1;`?

Comment: Same .. added output to original question so it would format.

Comment: You lost me at "The old way it was written, works".

Comment: A good example in the standard is [C11 Standard - 6.2.5 Types(29)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p29)

Comment: Sorry, Bob... I should have said, compiles.  But, I have not seen that syntax before (of declaring parameters before the function opening brace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution should not need any cast.

Examples of assigning a `const void *`

```
  const void *p1 = NULL;
  char *q1 = p1;        // warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type
  const char *q2 = p1;
  const char **q3 = p1; // warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type
  const char * const *q4 = p1;
  char * const *q5 = p1;
```

`const void *p1` points to `const` data.  The assignment target type needs to also be to a type that points to `const` data.  `q1` and `q3` above do not point to `const` data.  Either `q4,q5` will work for OP's compare.

```
int compare5(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
  char * const *pp1 = p1;
  char * const *pp2 = p2;
  return strcmp(*pp1, *pp2);
}
```

Comment: So, the "const data" in this context is the pointer to a const pointer? How does that pointer become a const *?  The data is setup as a char * *, so I could understand the "outermost" pointer (what is passed into compare) being const, but, as the rest was not defined const, what changes that?  Compiler magic?

Comment: @Jon "the "const data" in this context is the pointer to a const pointer?"  --> not quite.  In `compare5(const void *p1, ...)`, `p1` points to `const` something, that something is `void`.  With `something const *pp1`, `pp1` points to  a `const` something.   That _something_ happens to be a `char *`.

Comment: @Jon Further, `p1` is not `const`.  What it points to is `const`.  That is the same with `char * const *pp1 = p1;`.  `pp1` is not `const`, what is points to is `const`.   In the case of the original `(const char **)p1;`, the cast is not one where the pointer points to `const`  data, hence the warning.  It points to an non-`const` address.  That address does point to `const` data, yet the address itself is not `const`.

Comment: @Jon As an aside, it may help to think why `qsort()` passes a `const void *p1` and not something else.  The size of an element can be as small as 1 to very large like `SIZE_MAX`.  Passing a _copy_ of the elements could be _very_ inefficient. So `qsort()` passes the address of 2 elements.   With passing the address, `cmp()` could change the value of the element, but that is for `qsort()` to do the sorting, so `qsort()` passes a `const void *` to prevent `cmp()` from changing the elements.

Comment: I think the light is coming on, but I am puzzled by one difference. In the declaration `const void *p1`, you note that `p1` points to a `const void`.  But, in the case of `char * const *pp1`, you mention that pp1 points to a `const char *`.  Why is the `const` on alternate sides of the 'something' - the left in the case of the `void` and the right in the case of the `char *`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make what the pointer points to `const` as well:

```
const char *pp1 = *(const char * const *)p1;
const char *pp2 = *(const char * const *)p2;
```